# Can't get IP of vulnerable VMs

Tags: ip, virtualization

I have Kali Linux installed on my computer, I have VMware Workstation 15.5 downloaded on my Kali machine, and I have also vulnerable VMs on VMWare but I don't know how to get IP of vulnerable VMs like necromancer, Kioptrix, etc.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to find the IPs of the VMs you installed?

Comment: Yes, I just find it via Google but i can't get vulnerable VMs ip

Comment: This is not a security question. You need to understand how to use the virtualisation tools or how to log into the VM and get the IP from the OS tools in the VM.

Answer (score 1):

[Necromancer](https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/the-necromancer-1,154/) is using [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), which means that it gets an IP address from your local DHCP server.

1. Assuming you have the VM connected to your local home network, the
   DHCP server is most likely running on your home router. In this
   case, you can check which IPs are registered there and should be
   able to identify the right systems based on their lease time or
   their MAC address (which you can find in the network settings in
   VMWare).
2. If you have configured your VMWare environment to play DHCP, the
   VM will get its IP from VMWare directly. In this case you can
   simply restrict the DHCP range in VMWare to a single IP and
   thereby know, which IP the VM will get.

Comment: Yes, I know the theory behind. Please can you show me how to do it,with some commands? And also I have Bridged the network adapter setting in VMs.

Comment: @ZafirKhan - This depends on your infrastructure. The easiest way probably is logging in to your home-router, go to the DHCP menu and check the leases there.